# How to display particular section cells/items in centre horizontally in Collectionview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am displaying collectionview with 3 sections.

Each row I have to display 4 items, But, In second row I have to display only 3 items and those should be horizontally centre aligned.

I have tried to display centre aligned, But, Not getting out as expected.

```
//UICollectionViewDatasource methods
     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
           return 3
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 1 {
            return 2
        } else if section == 3 {
            return 4
        }
        return 4
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    
        cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if indexPath.section == 2 {
            //            let width = (collection.bounds.width - totalSpacing)/numberOfItemsPerRow
            return CGSize(width: 80, height: 60)

        } else {
            //            let width = (collection.bounds.width - totalSpacing)/numberOfItemsPerRow
            return CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
        }

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
           
           var cell =  CGSize()
           cell  = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height:100)
           return  cell
       }

    // custom function to generate a random UIColor
    func randomColor() -> UIColor{
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This would have been possible with `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol if your sizing layout was uniform. If you want this custom layout (display only some rows center align). You have to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and create sizing logic and save them calculated in layoutAttributes.frame, Firstly you would need to know which row is this where you want custom frame and map that to those cells for those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your collection view layout function at the section 2. Even `iPad` would not display 4 cell at row 1 because of static values.

```swift
if indexPath.section == 2 {
    let width = screenWidth * 0.5 - (leadingSpace + trailerSpace)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 60)
}
```

```swift
extension UIViewController {
      var screenWidth : CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    }
}
```

Consider iphone 11 for understanding. Width of iphone 11 is 414 
`cellWidthAtSection2` = screenWidth * 0.5 - (leadingSpace + trailerSpace)
`cellWidthAtSection2` = (414 * 0.5) - (16 + 16)
`cellWidthAtSection2` = 175